# How to define the action of $U(G)$ in this situation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, universal-algebra

The usual action of $fg$ on $u⊗v$ , where $f,g$  are elements in the Universal Enveloping Algebra $U(G)$ of a Lie algebra $G$ and $u,v$ are elements of a representation $V$ of $G$, is given by $fg(u⊗v)=fgu⊗v+fu⊗gv+gu⊗fv+u⊗fgv$, using the comultiplication, right? 
How to state this fact for $V^{\otimes n}$, i.e. $fg$  acting on $u⊗v$, where $u=\otimes_{i=1}^{n-k} u_i$ and $v=\otimes_{i=1}^k v_i$, for each $k=1,...,n-1$ ? 
Thanks,

Comment: The formula you've written is how fg acts on u⊗v. This is just the associativity of tensor product. Honestly, I don't think this is a very appropriate question for MO (you might get a better response on math.stackexchange.com). Actually, I think you would probably be better served by just going and reading a book about Hopf algebras, as all these points will be addressed in any reasonable one.

Comment: @Ben Webster: I have tried many books. But I haven't got any answer about this specific situation. I found in the Jantzen book that it is possible, but not how to do. Anyway, thanks for the link!

Comment: I would also suggest that you ask this on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is, I take it, the question you meant to ask at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43382/ ?

Comment: Chris, your formula only works when $f$ and $g$ are primitive elements.

Comment: Even if he is tripped up in the basics, it is a graduate-level question.  It seems dubious to bounce every easy question to math.stackexchange.com, even those that require graduate definitions.  In the limit, everything would be there except open problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing deep here.  The coproduct $\Delta : U(\mathfrak g) \to U(\mathfrak g)\otimes U(\mathfrak g)$ simply implements Leibniz's product rule: if $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$, then $x\in \mathfrak g$ acts on $V_1\otimes V_2$ by $x: v_1\otimes v_2 \otimes (xv_1)\otimes v_2 + v_1\otimes (xv_2)$.  Extending this, on a large tensor product we have:
$$ x(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n) = xv_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n + v_1 \otimes xv_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n + \cdots + v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes  \cdots \otimes xv_n$$
If $x,y\in \mathfrak g$, then $xy \in U(\mathfrak g)$ acts via the composition $x\circ y$.  For example,
$$ xy \left( \bigotimes_{k=1}^n v_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n (xy\text{ acts on }v_k) + \sum_{j\neq k}(x\text{ acts on }v_j\text{ and }y\text{ acts on }v_k)$$

Note that in general, for $f\in U(\mathfrak g)$, we do not have $f(u\otimes v) = fu \otimes v + u\otimes fv$.  For example, the constant $1$ is an element of $U(\mathfrak g)$, and $1(u\otimes v) = u\otimes v \neq 2u\otimes v = 1u\otimes v + u\otimes 1v$.  More generally, not all differential operators are derivations: certainly you do not expect $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ to satisfy a Leibniz rule!